# regex to parse out preceding backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, I am trying to split a string by ';' if not preceded (escaped) by '\'.

The string might look like:

```
asd;123;&auml\;;33;
```

So the above string should be split into:

- asd
- 123
- &auml\;
- 33

I thought [^\]; would do the trick but this selects the preceding character of ';' as well if it is not a '\'. I want only the ';' though without its preceding character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of splitting, you can match:

```
/(\\.?|[^;])+/g
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But this answer leads to:
["asd", "123", "**&auml**", "33"]
instead of 
["asd", "123", "**&auml\;**", "33"].
So your regex unfortunately works only if the input string was:
asd;123;&auml\\;;33;
Can you please update your solution?
Me personally, I thought it might be something like
/((^(\\;)|[^;]))+/g
So no \; or ; before a sequence of letters. But this still doesn't work.

Comment: @telandor: I think you might be putting your string in wrong. `'asd;123;&auml\;;33;'` is going to try to interpret the `\;` as a JavaScript string escape, and you’ll end up with just `;`. Escape the backslash too to put it in a string literal: `'asd;123;&auml\\;;33;'.match(/(\\.?|[^;])+/g)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the `.match` method, you can use this:

```
str = 'asd;123;&auml\\;;33;';
regex = /(?:\\;|[^;])+/g;
result = str.match(regex);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNbsG/3/)